# url link from email, how to open existing app tab and not reload app on new tab

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps

The user story:

On a browser, I have my Progressive Web App opened on any URL

```
https://mypwa.com/xxxx
```

I receive a mail, with a link to a page of my PWA

```
https://mypwa.com/post/<postId>
```

Instead of opening a new tab in the browser, I want my existing PWA tab to get the focus and go on the URL. I don't want a new tab nor a new PWA startup (it costs a lot in records download)

With postMessage, Service Worker can tell existing tab to get focus and go on the `/post/<postId>` path. Supposed to work but I get a "DOM Exception" on client.focus() in the service worker, from a fetch event, in short:

```
self.addEventListener("fetch", function(event) {
  var requestUrl = new URL(event.request.url);
  var pathname = requestUrl.pathname;

  if (
    event.request.mode === "navigate" &&
    requestUrl.origin === location.origin
  ) {
    const rootUrl = new URL("/", location).href;

    const mg = pathname.match(regexpPost);
    const postId = mg[1];

    event.waitUntil(
      clients.matchAll().then(matchedClients => {
        for (let client of matchedClients) {
          if (client.url.indexOf(rootUrl) >= 0) {
            return client
              .focus() //  ***** CRASHING HERE *****
              .then(() => {
                return sendMessageClient(client, { postId }).then(resp => {
                  other;
                });
              });
          }
        }
      })
    );
  }
});
```

What I'm missing also is how to close the newly opened tab. I don't want to keep it: dead tabs can accumulate and this is not a good user experience.

Tried javascript `window.close();` but it has to respond to a user action...

Comment: `client.focus()` is a method only available for `WindowClient` read more in the doc here : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/WindowClient/focus

Comment: Thanks for looking. Yeah I checked that, the type of "client" is well WindowClient, according to client.constructor.name. And error message wouldn't be "DOM Exception" if simply function missing.